# case sensitive lightning component name in summer 18 org

Tags: lightning, summer-18

I have a component which used to have a lightning:icon component as

```
<lightning:Icon iconName="utility:search" alternativeText="search" />
```

it used to work until winter 18. But I was testing on Summer 18 it was failing with error.

> Component class instance initialization error [Definition does not
>   exist on the client for descriptor:markup://lightning:Icon] Failing
>   descriptor:

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:search" alternativeText="search" />
```

So difference between two is only is **Icon > icon**. I looked into release notes to find if salesforce has removed case insensitivity of lightning component name. I event test with different lightning components they were also not working when name is used with capital letters.

Does salesforce changed this behaviour?

Comment: Hi @ManjotSingh. That's interesting. But what is the question?

Comment: does salesforce specified anywhere about this change? or this might be a bug they will fix

Comment: Lets wait for GA for Summer 18 before making any decisions. You can ask this on Release Readiness CHatter group. They seem to respond well there.
https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oku&fId=0D53A00003bpWPM

Comment: With lightning, assume case sensitivity for everything. In fact, assume it for ALL of your code and your peers will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce is going to roll back case sensitivity in summer 18 org. But they are saying that salesforce is going to implement case sensitivity in upcoming releases. Lightning:components were supposed to be case sensitive. They shared a link of summer 15 [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_lightning_case.htm). So you can check that all your components are case sensitive before upcoming releases.